# Incompatibility of Append and NumberForm?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the code

```
list = {.12, .23, .34};
Append[Round[list, .1], 10]
Append[NumberForm[list, 1], 10]
```

The use of Round returns the expected result `{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 10}`, whereas using `NumberForm` results in the error `NumberForm::argct: NumberForm called with 3 arguments."`. Am I missing something? Mathematica version is 10.0.2.0.

Comment: `Round` automatically threads over lists while `NumberForm` does not. So at the end you are appending to `NumberForm` not to the `List` which `list` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, just replace the built-in `Append` with some undefined `append` that does nothing and use `InputForm` to see what really happens

```
list = {.12, .23, .34};
append[NumberForm[list, 1], 10] // InputForm
(* append[NumberForm[{0.12, 0.23, 0.34}, 1], 10] *)
```

Now you see, that `NumberForm` is still wrapped around the list and you would append your 10 as 3rd argument which makes absolutely no sense.

In general you should only use things like `NumberForm` when you want to display something, because even when you *use* the syntax correctly

```
l2 = Append[NumberForm[#,1]&/@list,10]
(* {0.1,0.2,0.3,10} *)
```

is the resulting list really what you want? Look at the complete expression

```
InputForm[l2]
(* {NumberForm[0.12, 1], NumberForm[0.23, 1], NumberForm[0.34, 1], 10} *)
```

And now assume you want to get the `Min` from this list

```
Min[l2]
(* Min[10,0.1,0.2,0.3] *)
```

Doesn't work, because the numbers only *look like* numbers.

Comment: The horror of `NumberForm[0.12, 1] // ToBoxes` confirms this beyond doubt.